# How to create relative path in WiXSetup Project?

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an msi file by including several binaries into it. The path of the binaries are all absolute path, and I would like to change them to relative path. This is the code I have tried using in my wxs file as of now:-

```
<Component Id="OpenTap.Package.dll" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
<File KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\OpenTap.Package.dll" />            </Component>
```

I have defined the value of SourceDir in a wxi file under the same project as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<?include Config.wxi?>
```

When I build my project I keep getting the error "Schema validation failed with the following error at line 1, column 245: The element 'Wix' in namespace 'schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'Bundle Product Module Patch Fragment PatchCreation"

I am so confused what to do as I have been stuck on this for a while now

Comment: What's in your Config.wxi? Note that you need `<Include>`: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/overview/preprocessor/#include-files-include

Comment: I have put in the preprocessor <?define?> under the include tag

Comment: I assume you're building this with standard WiX tools, ie something that actually understands the preprocessor directives? And your Config.wxi contains only <?define?> statements and no text?

Comment: That's right, I have only included this line of code in my config.wxi file 
<?define SourceDir = "../../../External/blah?>

Interestingly the same code worked when I tried again after a reinstalling visual studio...not sure what is going on here. But now my code is able to detect only few of the binaries. It says "system cannot find the file" for the other binaries